# Is it possible to theme the tabris app clients?

Tags: css, eclipse

In the `com.eclipsesource.tabris` plugin there a two CSS files, `ios.css` and `theme-android-holo.css`. Can I change the theme with these two CSS files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Theming is not yet supported by the native Tabris clients.
The CSS files are used by the server to know the size of the native iOS and Android widgets. With this information the server is able to compute the correct layout.